Cross referencing in R-Quarto
It is kind of a very basic problem but since I could not find a solution, I just wanted to ask it.
So, when I was using R Markdown/R Studio, it would produce a citation, where I can click on the reference and it can take me to the references section of the document, around the place of the relevant citation.
Right now, when I started to use Quarto in R Studio and the do the same, although the relevant citation appears on the document, it is not referenced within the report, meaning that, when I click on the citation, it does not take me to the references section/page. Here is a minimal reproducible example in Quarto, which might help to understand what I am looking for;
---
title: "Untitled"
format: pdf
editor: visual
bibliography: fake_citations.bib
---

## Quarto

Here is a reproducible example [@neumann_norway_2010]

\newpage

Hey Hey Hey

\newpage

## References


The in-line reference of the output document is

and the end-reference is this;

So, what I would like to have is like, the in-line citation of (Neumann 2010) should be colored&cross-referenced within the document meaning that when one clicks on the in-line citation of (Neumann 2010), it can take him/her to the references section/page of the document. Thank you for your kind attention beforehand.

Can you share a Minimal working example?

Thank you for your comment. I have just tried to elaborate on my question. I hope it is more clear right now.

You are looking for link-citations: true.

If true, citations will be hyperlinked to the corresponding bibliography entries (for author-date and numerical styles only). Defaults to false.

---
title: "Untitled"
format:
  pdf:
    link-citations: true
bibliography: fake_citations.bib
---

More infos you can find here.


Thanks so much, it is a big relief for me. If I may, can I also ask how can I customize the hyperlink of in-line citation, such as changing its font/color and etc? Or, more generally, is it the same with R Markdown?
